# How to show Category image in one layout.?

Tags: magento2.2.0

I want to show category image in one layout, the layout in which product list is appearing.

Adding image through Catalog->Category->Category_name->Content->Categoy image.

Category page has 2column-left layout, one section have Compare Product and Wishlist and the second section have product listing.

I want it to display it in product listing section.